# Is there a way to download ALL addons for firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

For my final year uni project I am scanning firefox addons.

I need to download the .xpi for every possible extension, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: For clarification IF there is a way you'd only be able to download public extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could imagine sending GET requests to Mozilla website, e.g.
`https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v4/addons/search/?app=firefox&appversion=83.0&page=1&page_size=50&type=extension`
... then get .XPI files thanks to the URL you'll find in the "results" > "current_version".
And then do the same for page 2, ...
It should be easy to automatize (in Python or Bash for example), however you should program some sleep time between two requests in order to avoid overloading Mozilla's servers and / or being blacklisted.